# Getting failure in build for IntelliJ when compiling with Erlang plugin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, erlang

I am using erlang and Kotlin in my project and getting below error

> org/intellij/erlang/jps/model/JpsErlangModelSerializerExtension has
> been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file
> version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class
> file versions up to 52.0

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Do you use Thrift plugin? Please see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256900#focus=Comments-27-4997749.0-0). If so, try updating the Thrift plugin.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Ultimate Edition) and i failed issue with Erlang plugin which I have removed now. Link: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7083-erlang

Answer (score 5):

It got fixed in my case by uninstalling Erlang plugin from IntelliJ
IDEA

> Preferences → Plugins → Uninstall Erlang

Now, recompile and it should work.

Comment: I had the same problem in IntelliJ IDEA. I set configuration's java version to desired one (11 in my case) and set sdk version to 17 with language level 11 in Project Structure settings.

In this case I saved Erlang plugin without having to delete it.